# How to get all Linkedin Profile Posts with Linkedin Api

Tags: php, curl, linkedin-api

I need LinkedIn API for showing the feeds of my profile what I have posted from the day first. posts include media, images, video etc.

I had tried with LinkedIn **/share** endpoint but it returns an error like below,

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api?tabs=http#find-shares-by-owner)

```
[serviceErrorCode] => 0
[message] => Tunneled request must have 'Content-Type' header set to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or 'multipart/mixed'
[status] => 400
```

Here is code:

```
$url="https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:person:".$linked_profile['id'];
$headers[] = 'X-HTTP-Method-Override: BATCH_GET';
$headers[] = 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' .$_SESSION['linkedin_access_token'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
$result = json_decode($result,true);
```

Please help if anyone has done this before.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue last night. The error message is cryptic, but it means that your body format and `Content-Type` header don't match. In your case, the `Content-Type` header says the body should be a URL encoded form but you're not sending a body at all, you're putting the form in the query parameters. If you move the query parameters to the body, it'll work.

I know this is an old post but I expect many more to hit this issue soon as LinkedIn is changing some of their APIs effective April 30, 2022. [Here's a guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/query-tunneling-migration) to migrate to the new format.